# Dynamically adding tween to n MC's

Tags: actionscript-3

Here's what I'm aiming for. I'm querying the Rotten Tomatoes API for Upcoming Movies. For each movie returned, I'm creating an instance of MovieIcon (MC). I'm then adding this MC as a child of a Container MovieClip that's already on the scene. Each time, I'm incrementing the xPosition of each MovieIcon MC such that, they're positioned next to each other.

My container MC has a mask applied to it, therefore any child objects that are positioned beyond the size of the mask, they're are hidden from view.

How can I dynamically add a tween/easing animation between all these MovieIcon MC's so that when I hover over the Container MC, it 'scrolls' left or right, depending on the mouse motion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use one of the many tweening libraries out there -- Tweener, TweenMax, gTween, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend using a tweening library.
TweenLite and Tweener are good options

http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/ 
http://code.google.com/p/tweener/

Both of these include docs that will help you get everything set up in your project.

Then you should be able to add a ROLL_OVER event to each of your MovieIcon MC's

```
MovieIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, handleRollOver);
```

Inside your handler you can use the event.target property to get a handle on the over MovieIcon.
Assuming your using TweenLite you can go and add your tween to that target

```
private function handleRollOver(e:MouseEvent):void{
     TweenLite.to(e.target, duration, {x: new x value, any other prop: any other val})
}
```